# How to install node_modules into Docker image and use later WITHOUT docker compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-modules

How can I create a docker image with `node_modules` preinstalled, without `docker-compose`?

I know this is possible [using `docker-compose`](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) (see "Installing Dependencies"), but is it possible with just straight Docker?

Here's the broad strokes of what I'm trying to achieve (on CI):

1. Get a new commit
2. Is there a Docker image for the current branch? (Pulls tags from DockerHub)

   - YES => Has there been a change to `package.json` since that last image was built?

     - YES => Rebuild the image (do `npm i`); push it to DockerHub with a new tag
     - NO => Pull the last built image from DockerHub and use that
   - NO => Pull the last built image for `master` from DockerHub and use that
3. Mount current source code from commit to the image (newly built or pulled)
4. Do tests/linting/whatever, all without having to do `npm install` (because it's already done)

I've setup my CI to do all of that, but the built/pulled image doesn't have `node_modules` in the working directory when it comes time to run my tests/linting/whatever. That's what I need to figure out.

---

This is my `Dockerfile` so far

```
FROM node:8.1.2-alpine

RUN apk --update add --no-cache git
ADD git-branch /tmp/git-branch
RUN (cd /tmp/git-branch && npm install --silent --progress=false)
RUN mkdir -p /var/app && mv /tmp/git-branch/node_modules /var/app
RUN rm -rf /tmp/git-branch
```

Comment: volume is for linking a file/folder to your local filesystem, why don't you just use "COPY" and publish your docker image to use it then in another one ?

Comment: Because when I use it "in another one", when I add the directory containing the source code, `node_modules` will disappear. See http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html

Comment: The question is confusing. What is the end goal? To always use `node_modules` from the image and never from the mounted application folder?

Comment: @AndyShinn I edited my question to hopefully make it clearer. Basically yes, the `node_modules` in the working directory should always be from the container and never from the host.